# Linux untar the file with permissions

Tags: linux, unix, tar

I am getting an error- "Unknown file type 'A', extracted as normal file" while un-taring a set of files which has acl permissions set.

I had created the tar file in solaris as tar -cpfv Tarfilename.tar directory 
if I un-tar as tar xvpf Tarfilename.tar, it works great in solaris 
I had copied the tar file to Linux and tried to unatr using tar xvpf, 
it throws the warning Unknown file type 'A', extracted as normal file and created files without ACL permissions.

tar --version : tar (GNU tar) 1.15.1 in Linux

Comment: Are you sure about the tar invocation on Solaris?  *-cpfv* in my opinion should fail, as the f is meant to be the last option if you run them together like that.

Comment: I'm going to guess 'Linux tar doesn't support Solaris ACLs'...

Comment: ya in Linux -p option is failing- Unknown file type 'A', extracted as normal file. In solaris it works great. is there any other option like scp /.. [ scp failed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scp getfacl | setfacl  is the only one solution worked for me.[ haven't tried rsync yet]